# Reload jquery script different way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lastfm.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lastBox').lastplayed({
        apikey:         'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        username:       'myusername',
        limit:          6,
        refresh:        0
    });


});

</script>
```

that affects this div:

```
<div style="float:right;">


<h3>Recent Tracks</h3> <img src="np.gif" alt="" />
<img src="np.gif" alt="" />
<img src="np.gif" alt="" />
<img src="np.gif" alt="" />


<font size="2"><div id="lastBox" class="lastfm"></div></font>
```

the script isn't mine, i've taken it from [here](https://github.com/RingoRohe/lastfm-recent-tracks-jquery-plugin).
Now the problem is, that the "refresh" function already exists, but i turned it off because it's buggy, while the entire page reload works fine. So I've searched for a reload jquery script, i found some, but they all require a target html or php page to reload, while i just want to reload the div. Possibly, cound you try to look at the javascript [here](http://entspannt.altervista.org/lastfm.jquery.js) or by downloading it from the source link, and fix the reload there to make it act like the entire page is reloading? I'm quite new to all this. Thanks

Comment: How is it buggy? and what aaout using `setInterval` on the lastplayed function?

Comment: if i let the script refresh, it displays 2 times the same songs, the first with the "now" data, and the second one with the correct data. If i reload the page, the list is correct.

Comment: why not `setInterval(function(){ $('#lastBox').empty().lastplayed([YOUR API KEY AND USERNAME]); },2000)`?

Comment: where to replace that exactly? Sorry i'm quite a newbie.

Comment: after the first lastplayed call, and yes I can see :p

Comment: Sorry I tried but the syntax must be wrong. Could you please edit it for me so i see how to write it exactly? Thanks
    `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lastBox').lastplayed({
        apikey:         'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        username:       'myusername',
        limit:          6,
        refresh:        0
    });


});`